# Consultas por semana Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, date, querybuilder

tengo un problema con mis fechas. Veran, tengo una tabla llamada citamedica, de la que necesito extraer un cierto grupo de datos. Para ser mas precisos, cuantas citas existen para ginecologia, cuantas para cardiologia, para traumatologia y asi, con 12 especialidades.

Lo de contar el numero es sencillo, lo hago con un `count()`, el verdadero problema, es que necesito que las consultas se hagan de acuerdo a las semanas. Por ejemplo. Cuantas para ginecologia hubieron esta semana, la semana anterior, y la semana anterior a esa.

```
$fecha_actual = $this->fechaActual();
$fechaMenosUnaSemana =  date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 week"));
$fechaMenosDosSemanas =  date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 2 week"));



 $MedicinaGeneral = DB::table('fichamedica')
    ->join('Médicos','fichamedica.Medico_ID','=','Medicos.ID')
    ->where('Medicos.Especialidad_ID','=',1)
    ->whereBetween('fecha',[$fechaMenosUnaSemana,$fecha_actual])
    ->count();
```

He intentado esto. Primero calculo la fecha actual, luego le resto 1 semana, luego dos y uso esas fechas en un `whereBetween` para hacer la consulta entre esas dos fechas. El problema es que el `strtotime -1 week` lo que hace es restarme los 7 días.
Por ende, si yo hago la consulta un martes, me dirá todas las citas desde hoy martes hasta el anterior, cuando lo que quiero es que me cuente solo los de Lunes y Martes de esta nueva semana, en otra consulta me cuente los de la semana anterior (lunes a domingo) y asi. Como agrupados por semana.

Otro problema que tengo es que, como se podrán haber dado cuenta, tengo que hacer las mismas 3 consultas (Citas de esta semana, la semana pasada y la semana anterior a esa) para cada especialidad. Por lo que terminaran siendo 36 consultas, esto intentaré resolverlo con algún bucle, pero si conocen alguna mejor solución me gustaria oírla.

Comment: Bueno, son varias preguntas en una... Lo del primer día de la semana lo podrías hacer con carbon startOfWeek(), y a eso restarle 14 días. Con eso ya tienes la fecha inicial para consultar los registros a partir de esa fecha.

Comment: Qué sql usas? por ejemplo, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2... Pregunto porque  creo que con un par de expresiones raw podrías hacer todo con una sola consulta